# Porting Android regex to BlackBerry regex not working

Tags: regex, blackberry, java-me

I am using this code in Android to validate Password. But now want to use this expression in BB. But it is not working and giving exception

**This is Android Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public static boolean isUserPassValid(String userPass) {

        boolean isValid = false;
        try {
            String expression = "^.*(?=.{5,30})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-z]).*";
            CharSequence inputStr = userPass;

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                isValid = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "isUserPassValid Message = " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

**This is BB code that I am trying to validate in Java now**

```
import com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RE;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isValidPassword("Arsla");

    }

    public static boolean isValidPassword(String text) {
        System.out.println(" password for varefication is : " + text);
        boolean isValid = false;
        String expression = "^.*(?=.{5,30})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-z]).*$";
        String username = text;
        RE regx = new RE(expression);
        try {
            isValid = regx.match(username);
            System.out.println("password msps to the re " + isValid);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return isValid;
    }

}
```

**Here is Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RESyntaxException: Syntax error: Missing operand to closure
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.syntaxError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.terminal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.closure(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.branch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.expr(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.terminal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.closure(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.branch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.expr(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RECompiler.compile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RE.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RE.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Test.isValidPassword(Test.java:19)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Comment: the regex patterns in the two tests are difference. In the BB test, the regex has a `$` at the end. I've scanned through the code of `RECompiler` and it seems some of the character `*` causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please help to identify the correct regular expression for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the BB regex implementation does not support look arounds.

Try executing a simple look around example on both android and blackberry and see if it 
works. For example

```
String expression = "A(?=B)"; // only matches B if it follows an A
```

Comment: In BB it giving same exception. I am now trying following "^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{8,30}$"; It helping to get min 8 length Digit and latter. But not covering to ensure that It must contain at-least 1 digit or 1 latter.

Comment: look arounds are not supported by every regex implementation. As you have confirmed now, tha this is the source of the exception. Since you are never using the captures and only positive look-aheads, this regex should do match the same: `"^.*(.{5,30})(.*\\d)(.*[a-zA-z]).*$"`